# How accurate is mutagen track length info

Tags: mp3, id3, m4a, flac, mutagen

I'm doing some auditing of my music library (using Mutagen/Python), including looking for duplicates. In particular, I am writing a program to look for duplicates and I am using track-length as part of the way I compare two tracks. In the process of doing that, I'm finding some small discrepancies (say 2 seconds) between the track length of the mp3 version versus the m4a version.

Is this "real" (i.e., the different encoding distorts the track length - yikes!) or is this something to do with how the tags are created or how they are read?

If the difference is real and unavoidable, what comparison tolerance should I be setting for equality?

Comment: You haven't told us how you converted from mp3 to m4a.  Is it possible that the conversion introduced slight changes in the length of the track?  Separately: Have you tried computing the track length using any other tools or libraries, to cross-compare and try to validate the numbers you are getting from Mutagen?

Comment: Good points.   Id have to check the specific tracks as Ive used various conversions at different times, as well as simply two different uploads.  Ill do that and report back; also check Mutagen results against what my players report.  My question really is - if all such timings are +/- 2 or 3 seconds (which does sound a lot to me) then its a non issue.   Im just not sure what to expect.

Comment: @Andrew... I will have to extract the relevant code snippets, which I can do (may take a little while, Im going in to weekend mode!).  I will probably regret saying this, but I don't think the code is the issue.

Comment: Apologies for lack of progress, seasonal activities plus ice storm have been interfering.  However I have established that iTunes, at least, is reporting the same discrepancy at least in some cases.  So that suggests it's not mutagen but the conversion / ripping processes.